# Objective C how to read from nested JSON

Tags: ios, arrays, json, xcode, nested

I have to read some values from nested JSON and I can't read them properly.
JSON looks like this:

```
 "addons" : [
      {
        "group_title" : "Veggie Toppings",
        "group_type" : "T",
        "item_id" : "29",
        "addon" : [
          {
            "id" : "31",
            "item_title" : "Ham"
          },
          {
            "id" : "32",
            "item_title" : "Mushrooms"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "group_title" : "Meat Toppings",
        "group_type" : "T",
        "item_id" : "33",
        "addon" : [
          {
            "id" : "30",
            "item_title" : "Sausage"
          }
        ]
      }
```

And my code is:

```
-(void)setData:(NSMutableDictionary *)menuItems{
    self.menuItem = menuItems;
    // [GSDVActivityIndicator stopWithID:kNotificationHello];
    self.dictionaryOrder = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[self.menuItem valueForKey:@"order"]];
    self.arrayPrices = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self.menuItem valueForKey:@"price"]];
    self.arrayAddons = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self.menuItem valueForKey:@"addons"]];
    self.myAddons = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self.arrayAddons valueForKey:@"addon"]];

    [self setViewGUIData];

    NSLog ( @"addons= %@", [self.arrayAddons valueForKey:@"Group_title]);

    NSLog ( @"addon = %@", [self.myAddons valueForKey:@"item_title"]);

}
```

And the result is:

```
2014-03-24 19:48:04.446 [3698:70b] addons= (
    "Veggie Toppings",
    "Meat Toppings"
)
2014-03-24 19:48:04.447 [3698:70b] addon = (
        (
        Ham,
        Mushrooms
    ),
        (
        "Sausage"
    )
)
```

SO problem is in the second part where the items "ham, mushrooms and sausage" are in bad format and i can't read them and put them in label. Obviously this line is bad :

```
self.myAddons = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self.arrayAddons valueForKey:@"addon"]];
```

But i don't know how to correct it.

Thanks.

Comment: In second nslog you have "itemtitle" but key in dictionary is : "item_title", how it works?

Comment: the key names were in my native language so i edited them for the post, but that is not the problem, it works in Xcode, i just misspelled in this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is working correctly. The values for "addon" are `[{"id" : "31", "item_title" : "Ham"}, {"id" : "32", "item_title" : "Mushrooms"}]` and `{"id" : "30","item_title" : "Sausage"}`, so `valueForKey` is giving you an array containing those two values.

You don't say exactly what format you want, but I'm guessing you want a flat list. You can just make an array, iterate over the groups, and put in each addon:

```
NSMutableArray* addons = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray* groups = [self.menuItem valueForKey:@"addons"];
[groups enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary* group, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSArray* addonsInThisGroup = group[@"addon"];
    [addonsInThisGroup enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary* addon, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [addons addObject:addon];
    }];
}];
```

This would result in:

```
[
    {"id" : "31", "item_title" : "Ham"}, 
    {"id" : "32", "item_title" : "Mushrooms"}, 
    {"id" : "30","item_title" : "Sausage"}
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much:D now i get addon = (
    Ham,
    Mushrooms,
    "Ameci Sausage"
)
Do you know why are Ham and mushrooms without quotes?

Comment: When displaying strings in the console, it will use quotes only if it needs to. Ameci Sausage gets them because it has a space.

Answer (score 1):

Add [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) to your project files and turn JSON strings into dictionay objects.
Let's pretend your json datas are stored in a varaible called "responseString".
You just have to do this:

```
        NSArray *addons = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        addons = [[responseString objectFromJSONString] objectForKey: @"addons"];
```

Now in your array addons you'll have dictionary objects with keys "group_title", "group_type", "item_id" and "addon". Inside the object with the key "addon" you'll have an array of two dictionary objects with the keys "id" and "item_title".